# File content parsed instead of being included

Tags: php, xampp

I have just moved from my old, good, trusted apache + mysql bundle onto XAMPP and I am experiencing some major issues with getting it to work.

The first one I have not experienced in my whole life is seeing in my browser (under localhost) my class file... parsed (I see plain text of ecs_fpack_1.php in the browser), instead having it included to call the class. My former bundle handled it perfectly and I do not get the nature of this problem.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//
ob_start();
//
session_start();
//
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//
define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
define('BASE_ADDRESS', 'http://localhost/');
//

if (file_exists(BASE_PATH.'/ecs_fpack_1.php')) {
    require_once BASE_PATH.'/ecs_fpack_1.php';
    $core = new dc_core();
} else {
    die("Error");
}
?>
```

I get this error as well:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'dc_core' not found in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php
```

Thank you in advance for this and (probably) any other advices on how to get on with XAMPP.

Comment: Are you sure that your `ecs_fpack_1.php` has proper opening tag?

Comment: Nearly none of libraries I have got begin with <?php. They all begin with <?. I do not really feel like changing thousands of *.php files. Do you have any idea, good Sir, how to force XAMPP to treat <? equally with <?php?

Comment: php.ini `short_open_tag`

Comment: Thank you for your support. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other codes in your php files are working, the problem is that in `ecs_fpack_1.php` you don't have or have wrong opening php tag.

As we found - you have `<?` opening tag. Latest php releases use `<?php` tag as primary one. To enable using `<?` (which is called `short` tag), you need to enable it in php.ini, setting

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Finally, I advise you to **find** some time and replace all short tags. It will help to avoid problems in future.